# Invalid digit found in string ParseIntError

Tags: rust, error-handling

I am solving rustlings exercises and have issue with `errors2`, below is my code:

```
pub fn total_cost(item_quantity: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
let processing_fee = 1;
let cost_per_item = 5;
let qty = item_quantity.parse::<i32>();

let quantity_result = match qty {
    Ok(qty) => (qty * cost_per_item + processing_fee),
    Err(err) => panic!("invalid digit found in string {:?}", err),
};

    Ok(quantity_result)
}
```

`Ok` part works but I have no idea how to implement properly `Err` part. Here is a test for the code:

```
#[test]
fn item_quantity_is_an_invalid_number() {
    assert_eq!(
        total_cost("beep boop").unwrap_err().to_string(),
        "invalid digit found in string"
    );
}
```

Currently I have following message:

> panicked at 'invalid digit found in string ParseIntError { kind:
> InvalidDigit }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test is doing an `unwrap_err()`, meaning the test wants to see an `Err` returned from your function. You already *have* a `ParseIntError`, so return it instead of panicking; change this line

```rust
    Err(err) => panic!("invalid digit found in string {:?}", err),
```

to

```rust
    Err(err) => return Err(err),
```

That should let the test pass.

---

A further refinement of the code is to use the `?` operator, which is specifically for returning errors when they occur. Then you would replace the entire `match` with:

```rust
let quantity_result = qty? * cost_per_item + processing_fee;
```

or, more idiomatically, put the `?` on the line where the error occurred:

```rust
let qty = item_quantity.parse::<i32>()?;
```

so that `qty` itself is an `i32` and not a `Result<i32, ParseIntError>`.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that "by default" there is "return", it works!

Answer (score 1):

Your code panicked, because you explicitly told it to do so! You can read about error handling in rust in [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html) chapter of The Book, but here is the TL;DR version.

In general there are two types of errors in rust. The unrecoverable ones and recoverable ones. When you classify some errors as an unrecoverable one you can `panic` which will either unwind the stack and exit your process or straight up about it. `Option` and `Result` types have a method `unwrap` which will either give you the value or panic. You should use them when presence of `None` or `Err(_)` is a **bug**.

When you have a recoverable error (such as error in your example) you want to propagate it. The first thing doing so is usually returning a `Result`, which you are already doing. What you are doing wrong is that you are still panicking and not propagating this error. The solution is very simple. Just return the error! So you could write this instead:

```rust
pub fn total_cost(item_quantity: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    // ...

    match qty {
        Ok(qty) => Ok(qty * cost_per_item + processing_fee),
        Err(err) => Err(err)
        // alternatively use a bindig:
        // e @ Err(_) => e
    }
}
```

And test it with this:

```rust
#[test]
fn item_quantity_is_an_invalid_number() {
    assert!(total_cost("beep boop").is_err());
}
```

A very neat shorthand is the [question mark operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator), which allows you for propagating errors. Using it you could write your function this way:

```rust
pub fn total_cost(item_quantity: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let processing_fee = 1;
    let cost_per_item = 5;
    // Now the qty **is** i32! If parse would have returned
    // an error it would be returned from this function
    // and this line would never be reached.
    let qty: i32 = item_quantity.parse()?;

    Ok(qty * cost_per_item + processing_fee)
}
```

This does exactly the same as earlier version. In your example you can write it even more concise and use [`Result::map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map) method to `map` value if `Result` is `Ok` or do nothing in the case of `Err` variant. So lastly this function would look like this:

```rust
pub fn total_cost(item_quantity: &str) -> Result<i32, ParseIntError> {
    let processing_fee = 1;
    let cost_per_item = 5;
    
    item_quantity.parse().map(|q| q * cost_per_item + processing_fee)
}
```

I would recommend you read documentation of [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) and [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) and familiarize yourself with their methods, as there are *may* helpful methods that allow you to write short, expressive and idiomatic rust code.